# Convert LaTeX to HTML with MathJax

Tags: circuitikz, pandoc, mathjax, make4ht

I'm student for Computer science. I prefer to write my home work assignments in LaTeX. I'm utilizing tikZ pretty heavily in my specialized science courses. My goal now is to convert my TeX files to HTML+CSS+MathJax. I want everything that is supported by MathJax to be converted to MathJax and everything else (complex diagrams and drawings) to be simple converted to images (SVG/PGF).
I have tried to use Pandoc and Make4ht to achieve this goal with no success.
Pandoc makes a pretty good job of converting my common LaTeX to HTML+MathJax, but fell short when it comes to TikZ diagrams.
With Make4ht I have a great success with TikZ diagrams but I have several problems with the TeX itself.
Currently I have 2 problems:

1. make4ht doesn't convert my `\newcommand` macros.
2. make4ht can't use HTML color codes for cell filling in tables.
3. make4ht gnerates SVG images of TikZ diagrams but without text.

Here I'm providing a sample code and its result as it appears on my computer after invoking: `make4ht -ux file.tex "mathjax"`

```
\documentclass [11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2 cm]{geometry} %
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\n}[1]{\overline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]

                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline 
                    \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
                    \( \mathbf{x} \) & \( \mathbf{y} \) & \( \mathbf{(\n{x + y})} \) & \( \mathbf{\left( \n{\n{x} + \n{y}}\right)} \) & \( \mathbf{F} \)\\ \hline
                    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}0 \\ \hline
                    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}0 \\ \hline
                    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}0 \\ \hline
                    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}0 \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}%

            \end{table}


\( (\n{A} + B) \cdot \n{B} + \n{A}\n{C} + A \)


                \begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[] (A) {A}
(0,-0.5) node[] (B) {B}
(0,-1.5) node[] (C) {C}
(4,-0.5) node[or port] (myor) {}
(2,-1) node[nand port] (mynand) {}

(A) -| (myor.in 1)
(B) -| (mynand.in 1)
(C) -| (mynand.in 2)
(mynand.out) -| (myor.in 2)
(myor.out) node[anchor=west] {F}
;\end{circuitikz} 

\end{document}
```

Result from PDF
[image]

Result of HTML file:
[image]
[image]

As you can see make4ht did'nt interpreted `\n` macro. Also while running the command I did get this warning message:

```
    Argument of \c:HColor: has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.27 ...                   \rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}

?
```

Comment: Please, if the answer was useful for you, please consider [accepting it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update:

It is possible to use the direct  colors now. Try this version of `colortbl.4ht`:

```
% colortbl.4ht (2019-11-21-17:51), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 1997-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2019 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2019-11-21-17:51}


   \RequirePackage{xcolor}
\CT@everycr{\o:noalign:{\global\let\CT@row@color\relax}\the\everycr}
\def\columncolor#1{{\def\current@color{#1}%
                    \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname}}
\Odef\columncolor[#1]#2{{\if :#1:\def\current@color{#2}%
                         \else
                           \gHAdvance\tblcol:N by 1
                           \convertcolorspec{#1}{#2}{HTML}\tmp:tblcolor
                           \Configure{HColor}{tblcol-\tblcol:N}{\#\tmp:tblcolor}%
                           \def\current@color{tblcol-\tblcol:N}%
                         \fi
                    \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname}%
   \futurelet\:temp\left:colcol}
\def\left:colcol{%
   \ifx [\:temp \expandafter\left::colcol \fi
}
\def\left::colcol[#1]{
   \futurelet\:temp\right:colcol
}
\def\right:colcol{%
   \ifx [\:temp \expandafter\right::colcol \fi
}
\def\right::colcol[#1]{}
\HAssign\tblcol:N = 0
\def\CT@cellc#1[#2]#3{{\if :#2:\def\current@color{#3}%
                         \else
                           \gHAdvance\tblcol:N by 1
                           \convertcolorspec{#2}{#3}{HTML}\tmp:tblcolor
                           \Configure{HColor}{tblcol-\tblcol:N}{\#\tmp:tblcolor}%
                           \def\current@color{tblcol-\tblcol:N}%
                         \fi
                    \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname}%
   \futurelet\:temp\left:colcol}
\NewConfigure{@classz}{4}
\pend:def\@classz{\pic:gobble\a:@classz}
\append:def\@classz{\pic:gobble\b:@classz}
\pend:def\insert@column{\pic:gobble\c:@classz}
\append:def\insert@column{\pic:gobble\d:@classz}
\def\:temp{\global\let\CT@do@color\relax}
\HLet\CT@@do@color\:temp
\let\::maketitle\o:maketitle:
\def\o:maketitle:{%
   \ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
      \NewConfigure{@classz}{4}%
      \Configure{@classz}{}{}{}{}%
   \fi
   \::maketitle }
\def\rowcolor{%
  \o:noalign:{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \global\let\CT@do@color\CT@@do@color
  \relax
\ifx\LT@head\Un:Def\else
   \ifnum \HRow=0\relax
      \expandafter\ifx\csname lt:sv\endcsname\relax
        \HAssign\HRow = 1\relax
        \ifvoid\LT@head
           \ifvoid\LT@firsthead \else \HAdvance\HRow by 1\relax\fi
        \else \HAdvance\HRow by 1\relax\fi
      \else
        \HAssign\HRow = \lt:sv \relax
        \HAdvance\HRow by 1\relax
      \fi
\fi\fi
%
  \@ifnextchar[\CT@rowa\CT@rowb}
\def\CT@rowa[#1]#2{%
  \save:color#1 #2//% 
  \pic:gobbleII\a:rowcolor{#2}%
  %\pic:gobbleII\a:rowcolor{#1 #2}%
  \gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#2}}%
  \CT@rowc}
\def\CT@rowb#1{%
  \pic:gobbleII\a:rowcolor{#1}%
  \gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#1}}%
  \CT@rowc}
\NewConfigure{rowcolor}{1}
\def\convert:colorspec#1 #2 #3 #4{%
  \edef\current:color{%
    \ifx\relax#1\relax\else%
    #1\ifx\relax#2\relax\else%
    , #2\ifx\relax#3\relax\else%
      , #3\ifx\relax#4\relax\else%
        , #4%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  }%
}

\def\save:color#1 #2//{%
  \typeout{*******************}
  \typeout{color: #1, #2}
  \convert:colorspec#2 {} {} {} {}
  \convertcolorspec{#1}{\current:color}{HTML}\tmp:col
  \def\current@color{#2}
  \Configure{HColor}{\current@color}{\#\tmp:col}
}

\def\begin:current@color{\let\sv:curcolor\current@color}
\def\end:current@color{%
   \ifx \current@color\sv:curcolor
   \else%
   \expandafter\save:color\current@color//%
   \csname a:text-colortbl\endcsname
   \fi
}
\NewConfigure{text-colortbl}{1}
\def\GET@column@color{}
\def\color:ii[#1]#2#3!*?: {\def\:temp{#1 #2}}
\def\color:i#1#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#1}}
\let\ctbl:mcol\multicolumn
\def\multicolumn#1#2#3{%
   \ctbl:mcol{#1}{#2}{#3}%
   \expand:after{\expandafter\MUL:LMN\meaning\@preamble}\MUL:PA//%
   \ignorespaces}
{
  \def\MUL:PA{\gdef\MUL:PA}
  \def\MUL:LMN{%
  \catcode`\C=12
  \catcode`\T=12
  \catcode`\@=12
  \catcode`\c=12
  \catcode`\o=12
  \catcode`\l=12
  \catcode`\r=12
  \catcode`\t=12
  \catcode`\e=12
  \catcode`\m=12
  \catcode`\p=12
  \catcode`\d=12
  \catcode`\i=12
  \catcode`\b=12
  \gdef\MUL:LMN}
  \MUL:LMN#1CT@color #2@tempdimb#3//{\::KOLOR{#2}}
  \MUL:PA{CT@color @tempdimb}
}
\def\::KOLOR#1{\if :#1:\else \:KOLOR#1//%
\fi}
\def\:KOLOR{\@ifnextchar[\mc:clr{\mc:clr[]}}
{
  \catcode`\{=12
  \catcode`\}=12
  \catcode`\(=1
  \catcode`\)=2
  \gdef\mc:clr[#1]{#2}((%
       \def\current@color(\if :#1:\else #1 \fi #2)%
       \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname
     )\def\:temp##1//()\:temp)
)
\NewConfigure{cell-colortbl}{1}


\Hinput{colortbl}
\endinput
```

---

**Original answer:**

I can compile your file with `tex4ht` with small changes.

There are  three issues that need to be fixed: missing definition of the `\n` command in MathJax, color issues and issues with the TikZ graphics.

For TikZ, I would use the [alternative driver](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht). It uses Dvisvgm for the conversion and produces much better result than the default driver. Especially for the text nodes.

The issue with `\n` command is caused by the fact that `tex4ht` cannot process the math content in the MathJax mode. It can be fixed with a simple configuration for MathJax.

The color issues can be fixed using named colours instead of use of the direct values.
It is also necessary to provide an alternative definition for the `\cellcolor` command, because it is not supported by `tex4ht` by default.

Here is the modified TeX file:

```
\documentclass [11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2 cm]{geometry} %
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\n}[1]{\overline{#1}}
% \definecolor[HTML]{lightgreen}{rgb}{67FD9A}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]

                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline 
                    \rowcolor{lightgray} 
                    \( \mathbf{x} \) & \( \mathbf{y} \) & \( \mathbf{(\n{x + y})} \) & \( \mathbf{\left( \n{\n{x} + \n{y}}\right)} \) & \( \mathbf{F} \)\\ \hline
                    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{lightgreen}0 \\ \hline
                    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{lightgreen}0 \\ \hline
                    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cellcolor{lightgreen}0 \\ \hline
                    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \cellcolor{lightgreen}0 \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}%

            \end{table}


\( (\n{A} + B) \cdot \n{B} + \n{A}\n{C} + A \)


                \begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[] (A) {A}
(0,-0.5) node[] (B) {B}
(0,-1.5) node[] (C) {C}
(4,-0.5) node[or port] (myor) {}
(2,-1) node[nand port] (mynand) {}

(A) -| (myor.in 1)
(B) -| (mynand.in 1)
(C) -| (mynand.in 2)
(mynand.out) -| (myor.in 2)
(myor.out) node[anchor=west] {F}
;\end{circuitikz} 

\end{document}
```

The main changes are the use of the alternative driver:

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
```

and use of the named colours:

```
\rowcolor{lightgray} 
\( \mathbf{x} \) & \( \mathbf{y} \) & \( \mathbf{(\n{x + y})} \) & \( \mathbf{\left( \n{\n{x} + \n{y}}\right)} \) & \( \mathbf{F} \)\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cellcolor{lightgreen}0 \\ \hline
```

Here is the configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{HColor}{lightgreen}{\#67FD9A;} 
\makeatletter
\def\CT@cellc#1[#2]#3{{\def\current@color{#3}%
                    \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\detokenize{%
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
      Macros: {
        n : "\\overline",
      }
    },
    }
  );
</script>
}}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It defines the `lightgreen` color, because all colors must be configured for `tex4ht`. `lightgray` is defined by default:

```
\Configure{HColor}{lightgreen}{\#67FD9A;}
```

the next lines redefine a macro used by `\cellcolor` internally to use the `tex4ht` configurations for cell colors:

```
\def\CT@cellc#1[#2]#3{{\def\current@color{#3}%
                    \csname a:cell-colortbl\endcsname}}
\makeatother
```

And finally, using the following configuration we define the `\n` macro for MathJax:

```
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\detokenize{%
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
      Macros: {
        n : "\\overline",
      }
    },
    }
  );
</script>
}}}
```

Compile your file using

```
 make4ht -ul -c config.cfg filename.tex "mathjax,svg"
```

This is the result:

[image]